# Oracle SQL Insert row with values and select

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I insert a row into a table with some of the attributes been hard coded values and some of the attibutes from select statement?

I know how to insert pure values and pure select statement, but can I do both at the same time?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have and what you want to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a combination; for example

```
insert into emp (empno, ename, job, salary)
select seq.nextval, 
       ename,
       'CLERK',
       1000
from old_emp;
```

where

- `empno` gets its value from a sequence
- employee name (`ename`) is from old_emp table
- `job` and `salary` are *hardcoded*